# php not reacting on cyrillic text

Tags: php, encode, telegram-bot

i am writing a telegram bot on PHP so there's a problem.

```
     <?php

  header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

  $token="*********";
  $website="https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token;

  $upd=file_get_contents("php://input");
  $updarray=json_decode($upd,true);
  $text=$updarray["message"]["text"];
  $chatId=$updarray["message"]["chat"]["id"];
  $chat=$updarray["message"]["chat"]["type"];
  $name=$updarray["message"]["from"]["username"];
  $text=mb_strtolower($text);


  if ($text=="/start")
      $reply="Hello, $name. I know three languages! Kazakh, Russian, and English. Greet me in your language and I will answer you back!";
  else if ($text=="/stop")
      $reply="Bye, $name.";
  else if ($text=="hello" || $text=="hey"  || $text=="hi")
        $reply="Hello, $name";
  else if ($text=="привет" || $text=="hai"  || $text=="хай")
      $reply="Привет, $name";
  else if ($text=="salem" || $text=="калайсын")
      $reply="Салем, $name";
  else
      $reply="Bye-bye!";

  $sendmes=$website."/sendMessage?chat_id=".$chatId."&text=".$reply;
  file_get_contents($sendmes);

  ?>
```

it reacts on latin letters but no reaction on cyrillic. it reacts on "hai" but not "хай". so what can i do?
p.s. as you see i'm newbie on these things.

Comment: variable `$name` is not set in your example. I tested your code and it works as expected, what output are you getting?

Comment: @B-and-P it's just part of my code.  everything is  ok except that bot not reacting on cyrillic messages

Comment: have you checked `$text` by printing?

Comment: check your encoding throughout application, should be UTF-8, I believe

Comment: @B-and-P so how can i set UTF-8?

Comment: @B-and-P set this at the top of your page header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: @RedCrusador it's still not working

Comment: @neomendax save this file in your editor as UTF-8 , which editor you use?

Comment: What is the output of the following two lines: `echo ini_get('default_charset');  echo mb_detect_encoding($text);`?

Comment: @B-and-P output ASCII

Comment: Both of the `echo` statements?

Comment: I haven't seen yet `default_charset` to be set to ASCII, normally it is UTF-8. try changing it and see fi it helps, add at the top of your code `ini_set('default_charset' , 'UTF-8');`

Comment: @B-and-P now its showing nothing and still not reacting on messages

Comment: @neomendax Try `mb_strtolower($text, 'UTF-8')`

Comment: @JoeBlack thanks! works great!